# Is it possible to install a linux based OS on an android tablet as dual boot exactly like a desktop?

Tags: dual-boot, remote, android, tablet

My problematic is the following. I have a desktop (Ubuntu 18.04) where there is my databases and it can be used as a server. With a trivial laptop using a Linux OS I can easily communicate with my desktop by using [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) connected on it, [Mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/) and so on. Well using my desktop as force of computing and my laptop as an interface with "poor" computing capacities.

The problem is I don't have laptop now, but I have an Android Tablet [Samsung Galaxy Tab A 8.0 (2019)](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_A_8.0_(2019)_(samsung-gtowifi)).
It is compatible and tested with PostmarketOS as far as I know but there is something I dislike:
["Beware that by following these instructions, you will overwrite everything that is currently on your device. You will lose all data and it might not be possible to restore the original operating system. There is a risk of hard-bricking your device, meaning it may be impossible to recover without specialist tools. "](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Installation_guide)

This is not what I am looking for. I don't want to replace my Android OS on it which is fine for other purposes. I would like to use it like a desktop where Grub give you the possibility to use the OS you want at the moment. Besides is it possible to install the OS and use it from a microSDcard in order to economize tablet storage's space ? Theoretically an OS can be installed on any storage peripheral storage device (like diskette a long time ago).

I know this is very general and there is maybe better option for the purpose I described at first in this topic. I am open minded about other solutions to answer this need because I am not very aware about all the pros and cons.

Comment: Android (ARM) devices have a drastically different set of hardware, thus installing Linux on them is a risky business. I'd *not* recommend installing Linux on your tablet. Please try looking for a working Android ROM/distro instead. In Linux many features of your tablet might not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to install a linux based OS on an android tablet as dual boot exactly like a desktop?

No. A desktop PC has well-defined interfaces with which an operating system can detect which devices are there, and how to talk to them.

An embedded device like a phone does not have that. You must tailor your operating system exactly to the phone you're using.

That's why you can't run e.g., an Android image for a Samsung Galaxy S9 on a OnePlus 6 — even if they're based on the same processor / SoC. You need all information on which hardware is attached how, and drivers integrated exactly in the right kernel.

So, no. Since there's no "general" abstraction of how "phone hardware" can be used, there's no "general" OS that runs on different phones. Someone always has to taylor things. That's why there's e.g. LineageOS (a version of Android) for some phones, but not for others: it literally takes someone to sit down and do a lot of work for *anything* to boot on a phone.